# Display child pages on a parent and child page using Featured Thumbnails

Tags: post-thumbnails, child-pages

How would I display a list of my child pages using featured images on a its parent page as well as its other siblings child page?

For example, if my parent page is called 'Music', I'll have my main content with child pages thumbnails at the bottom.

I'd like to have thumbnails with permalinks to other child pages from within the parent Music page displayed across all of the child music pages.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: There are a number of related questions to the right under "Related". Do none of those help?

Comment: Some of these are useful, but i'm still in need to post the thumbnails with permalinks of child pages, when even on other child pages from the same parent page?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) to get the page parent, then get the children of that parent.

```
$ancestors = array();
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID,'page');
$parent = (!empty($ancestors)) ? array_pop($ancestors) : $post->ID;
if (!empty($parent)) {
  $kids = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_parent'=>$parent,
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    )
  );
  if ($kids->have_posts()) {
    while ($kids->have_posts()) {
      $kids->the_post();
      echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I link the thumbnails to their permalink pages?

Comment: @David : see the edit

Comment: without specifying `posts_per_page => -1` you will be limited to only the number that is set in admin. (usually 10) Also this seems it would only work on child pages, but not on the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution worked so far for me, which is combination of multiple solutions i found online,

With this code you can display Sub Page Featured Image and Title with anchor link.

Also this work for Sub and Child page too.

```
<!--Child Page Thumbnails Start-->
<?php 
  $subs = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
      'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
      'post_type' => 'page', 
      'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' 
    )
  );
if( $subs->have_posts() ) : 
  while( $subs->have_posts() ) : 
    $subs->the_post();
    echo '<article class="span_8 col clr-margin products-thumb"> <a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a>'.'<br/><h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2></article>';
  endwhile; 
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<!--Child Page Thumbnails End-->
```

Comment: I have 2 worries about this - doesn't the `meta_key` argument limit the pages to only ones with actually having the thumbnail? Wouldn't a fallback thumbnail image be more generic solution? Also without specifying `posts_per_page => -1`, you'd be only limited to the number of posts set in admin.