# Query Pages and post excerpts dynamically

Tags: php, functions, child-pages, excerpt

I have a custom home page, a blog page which includes a dynamic preview area of the latest 5 blogs, and some other miscellaneous pages. Im trying to design an "events" page where the main page has a sidebar that looks like this:

[http://imgur.com/ezEIApD](https://imgur.com/ezEIApD)

You can then click on each section, which will open up and have a brief description of the event taken from the page with a read more link to go to that page.

[http://imgur.com/Gz9RDYx](https://imgur.com/Gz9RDYx)

I have a parent page called "Events Main" and then I have some test pages set up as child pages of the "Events Main" page.

How I could go about querying child pages to fill in that content dynamically?

I'm currently using this code

```
$page_id = 85;
$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
$content = $page_data->post_excerpt;
$title = $page_data->post_title;
echo $page_data->post_title;
echo $page_data->post_excerpt;
```

but I have to go in and fill the page ID number for each section. I need it to automatically populate these fields, so whenever a new child page is added it will show up.

Im using a very similar method in the blog part of my page where anytime a new post is added, the shows up on the blog home page and i can then click it to go to the actual post using this code:

```
    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=5"); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div style="color:#fff;" <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">


        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>    </h2>
        <div id="imageScript"><?php if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) { get_the_image(); } ?></div><!-- END imageScript -->
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="meta"><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?></div><!-- END meta -->
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Not Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102678/21376

Comment: I've left a solution for you on the [Stack Overflow copy of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17885720/329911). Hope it helps you!